# Indent Continuation Lines in nxml-mode

Tags: nxml

A style guide for DocBook XML that I must adhere to states "Content within elements should be indented by two spaces if the content runs over more than one line."  They give this example.

```
<para>See the <link
    linkend="gmirror-troubleshooting">Troubleshooting</link>
  section if there are problems booting.  Powering down and
  disconnecting the original <filename>ada0</filename> disk
  will allow it to be kept as an offline backup.</para>

<para>It is also possible to journal the boot disk of a &os;
  system.  Refer to the article <link
    xlink:href="&url.articles.gjournal-desktop;">Implementing UFS
    Journaling on a Desktop PC</link> for detailed
  instructions.</para>
```

They also state that,

> Tags containing long attributes follow the same rules.
>   See the `linkend` element of the `link` tag.

None of the customizable `nxml-mode` variables seem to help.  In fact, some of the docstrings describe the opposite behaviour.

`nxml-child-indent`:

> This only applies when the line or lines containing the start-tag
>   contains nothing else other than that start-tag.

`nxml-attribute-indent`:

> Indentation for the attributes of an element relative to the
>   start-tag.

I think I prefer keeping opening an closing tags on separate lines like `nxml-mode` promotes.  Unfortunately the guide specifically prohibits some "straggling" tags (tags on their own line).

Am I out of luck conforming to this style guide with `nxml-mode`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're indeed partly out of luck.  nxml-mode is good at parsing the file and providing on the fly validation, but indentation was a secondary goal.  You would probably be better served by sgml-mode's indentation.

This said, you could try

```
(add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (require 'sgml-mode)
            (setq-local indent-line-function #'sgml-indent-line)))
```

It's quite possible that it will misbehave in various cases (e.g. because the syntax-tables are setup very differently), but if you're interested, I'd be happy to try and help you get it working well and integrate that change into Emacs.

Comment: I had considered something similar after noticing `sgml-mode` indents in way that (nearly) matches the style guide. Unfortunately, locally setting `indent-line-function` to `sgml-indent-line` seems to completely break indenting in `nxml-mode`. Thanks for your offer to help.  I will have a look at the code and depending on what I find, I may take you up on your offer.

Comment: A partial solution may be to create a variable `nxml-continuation-offset`.  I think this could be used in `nxml-compute-indent-from-matching-start-tag`.  If the default for `nxml-continuation-offset` were 0, then the default behaviour would not change.  What do you think?  Do you have any specific tips on how to do this?

Comment: Also, would you prefer to move the discussion to emacs.devel?

Comment: I think I spoke too soon when I said "locally setting `indent-line-function` to `sgml-indent-line` seems to completely break indenting in nxml-mode".  It does improve some things, but a problem is the DocBook file I'm working on starts with a `chapter` tag.  After setting the variable all indentation reports the `chapter` tag isn't closed and so the indentation for the rest of the file is borked.

Comment: This problem with an unclosed tag seems like something that shouldn't be too hard to fix.